# Avago/LSI flash tool does not detect SAS card

Tags: raid, lsi, firmware, firmware-update

I'm trying to reflash my LSI 9300-4i (M1210) RAID card but hitting a wall.  First of all, my BIOS detects the card as shown here:

[image]

And then I've tried booting DOS, Windows 10, and EFI shell.  When I run the sas3flash tool it always reports "No Avago SAS adapters found".  Why not?  The BIOS says it's present.

[image]

In case it helps I'll add a picture of my card below.  Can someone explain why I can't flash the ROM+firmware, and what I need to do differently?

Please note that I am unable to enter the configuration utility for the card via the ROM on boot, as it is somehow disabled.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that my LSI card is in fact an OEM edition (branded as "IBM").  Once the avago tools see the OEM flag (or OEM name) in the ROM they refuse to run.  Apparently older (early sas2flash) tools ignored this and would reflash the rom & firmware.  Once re-flashed the card identifies as LSI and then all LSI tools work normally.  But newer LSI tools (eg sas3flash) refuse to run on OEM branded products, and only work on LSI branded products.  This makes sense - we support other brands which aren't paying you for support.

The only way to solve this is boot to DOS, then run megarec to wipe the firmware and bios.  Then write the new firmware and bios.  After that the regular sas3flash tools will work because they see an LSI branded card.